# laravel localhost:8000

Tags: php, laravel

`php artisian serve` - пишу этот код на `cmd`.

Когда открыто `cmd`, заходит через адрес `localhost:8000`, а когда закрываю `cmd`, не заходит через этот адрес. Помогите...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы исполняете команду `php artisan serve`, cmd.exe, в которой вы ее исполняете, создает новый процесс, вывод которого печатается на экран, и который и есть тот самый `php artisan serve` - процесс встроенного в PHP веб-сервера. Когда вы закрываете какой-либо процесс, ему посылается сигнал, и этот процесс либо просто умрет, оставив свои дочерние процессы своему родителю, либо предпримет какие-либо действия. cmd является пользовательской консолью, и поэтому все *простые* дочерние процессы считаются процессами, которые пользователь запустил, и которые стоит убить вместе с закрытием консоли - если пользователь закрыл консоль, то и исполняющиеся в нем процессы пользователю не нужны.

Таким образом при закрытии консоли убивается интересующий вас процесс. Воспрепятствовать этому можно несколькими способами, но раз вы силите на windows, я бы порекомендовал просто поставить OpenServer.

Answer (score 1):

Кажется очевидным, что при закрытии программы больше некому принимать соединения. Работающая программа - необходимое условие для приема соединений.